# Getting an issue while executing delete command on multiple tables concurrently

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I am using oracle database to delete data from two tables concurrently using executer interface,but it is able to delete only data from one table,from other table it is getting hanged.On debugging,it is getting hanged at 
`var5 = (short)this.inStream.read() in unmarshalUB1() method of T4CMAREngineStream class of odbc7`.
Can anyone please let me know,how to adress this?

Sample Code:

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)
                    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
           // final Connection conn=dbm.getConnection();
           // boolean autoCommit = conn.getAutoCommit();
           // conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            for (final Table t : <Tables>) {
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            startArchieveConcurrently(t);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.info("ex::"+e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


public void startArchieveConcurrently(DbMetaData.TableInfo t) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.
                getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HID>:1521:<SID>"
                        ,"UNAME","PWD");
            try {
                boolean autoCommit = conn.getAutoCommit();
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            dcount = deleteByDate(t, ts,conn);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.info("Error processing table: " + t.getTableName(), ex);
            doRollback(conn);
        }
        finally {
                conn.close();
            }
        logger.info("Finished,table is::"+t.getTableName() + "::" +Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
```

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver and the version of Oracle (full version please!)

Comment: ojdbc7,oracle 12c

Comment: Those are **not** full versions. BTW: If you're using Oracle 12c, why did you tag with Oracle11g?

Comment: Could not get oracle 12c in tag,what do you mean by full version?

Comment: For full version, for example Oracle JDBC 11.2.0.4 or Oracle JDBC 12.2.0.1. Oracle database itself has similar version numbers.